# Understanding reference levels in circuits

Tags: basic, voltage-reference, over-voltage-protection

I understand that a zener diode uses its anode as a reference to limit the over-voltage levels that appear on its cathode. However, in the [circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu1HuxDV6GM) shown below, I am confused about why the anode of the Zener diode is connected to the PACK+ pin when we want to suppress all voltage spikes above 16V.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> we want to suppress all voltage spikes above 16V.

Let me rewrite that in a way that's less ambiguous:

"We want to prevent a certain ***potential difference*** from exceeding 16V".

The way it's drawn, it isn't immediately obvious, but the two circled zener diodes are connected between the gate and source of a MOSFET, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDoH2z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When potential \$V_G\$ at the gate exceeds source potential \$V_S\$, so that \$V_G > V_S\$, the diode is reversed biased, and normally doesn't conduct at all. But being a zener diode, when the difference \$V_G - V_S\$ approaches +16V, the diode begins to conduct heavily, which has the effect of preventing the two potentials \$V_G\$ and \$V_S\$ from separating any further.

Therefore gate potential cannot ever be more than 16V higher than source potential. In other words, the potential ***difference*** \$V_G - V_S\$ is constrained to a maximum of +16V:

$$ V_G - V_S < +16V $$

A similar constraint is imposed when the diode is forward biased, which happens when \$V_G < V_S\$. In that condition the diode behaves just like any regular diode, and begins conducting heavily as the potential difference \$V_G - V_S\$ approaches -0.7V. Therefore:

$$ V_G - V_S > -0.7V $$

These two constraints together ensure that \$V_G - V_S\$ is always kept within the range −0.7V to +16V. If I define \$V_{GS} = V_G - V_S\$, this could be written:

$$ -0.7V < V_{GS} < +16V $$

Take a look at the [IRF540 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91021/irf540.pdf), or the datasheet of any typical MOSFET. You'll find something like this:

[image]

This table tells you the limits that the device can withstand. It says that "Gate-source voltage" \$V_{GS}\$ must never be outside the range \$-20V < V_{GS} < +20V\$. That's the same \$V_{GS}\$ I was talking about above.

As we already established, in your circuit \$V_{GS}\$ is kept in the range \$ -0.7V < V_{GS} < +16V \$, by the zener diode, meaning that the constraints on \$V_{GS}\$ as stated in the datasheet are always obeyed.

That's the purpose of those diodes; to keep \$V_{GS}\$ within acceptable limits.

Answer (score 2):

In this application they want to limit the MOSFET positive gate voltages to be no more than 16 V above the source voltage, so the MOSFET source is the reference and therefore the Zener anode is connected there. The voltage with respect to ground at that point is irrelevant, whether it be BAT+, PACK+ or whatever, we're only interested in the gate to source differential voltage.